# Can't connect to Lacie Cloudbox when connecting directly to PC

Tags: networking, windows-8, ethernet, nas

I have bought a [Lacie-Cloudbox NAS](http://www.lacie.com/products/product.htm?id=10597) to backup my PC. I can connect it to my router and access it without problems. For the initial backup of my data I want to connect the Cloudbox directly to my PC using the ethernet cable to have faster file transfers. The problem is that Windows can't detect the device.

It's not in the network and I can't connect it via browser either. Even the official Lacie Network Assistant can't find it.
What I am missing?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the problem is a missing driver, do the following :

Connect the Cloudbox to only the PC, re-power it up completely (apparently needs 3-9 minutes), then reboot the PC.

Look for any message about new or unidentified devices. If none, look in Device Manager for any yellow icons or something "Lacie" in the sections of Disk Drives / Storage controllers / Network adapters.

Use the information gathered to search for a driver, or report your findings here
if you need help.

[EDIT]

The [manual says](http://manuals.lacie.com/en/manuals/cloudbox/administration) that the CloudBox behaves as a local Web server that can be accessed via `http://ip-address` or `http://CloudBox` or `http://CloudBox.local` .

I think that the problem with connecting it directly to the computer is that [DHCP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_Host_Configuration_Protocol)
is needed in order to have an IP address. The router is a DHCP server and every device
on the network gets its IP address from the router when connecting.
To connect directly, you will need to substitute the router's DHCP services by these of your computer.

The steps to follow should be :

- Disconnect the router from your computer and from the CloudBox
- Connect the CloudBox directly to your computer
- [Turn on DHCP in windows 8](http://mywindows8.org/how-to-turn-on-dhcp-in-windows-8/)
- Reboot your computer
- Reboot the CloudBox

You should now in theory be able to see a "CloudBox" computer in your network
and should be able to access the dashboard by one of the above methods.

Just to remark that it is not guaranteed that the resulting transfer speed will
be any faster than via the router. For really faster speeds you would need USB,
which I believe is not supported by the CloudBox.

You will need to turn off DHCP on Windows 8 when connecting back to the router.

Going to static IP addresses for both the CloudBox and your computer, if possible,
might be simpler than using DHCP.

Comment: I cant find anything related to missing devices or drivers. The Lacie Network assistant can find it now but still cant connect. I couldnt test much because I am having a problem with my PC. I will test it again in the weekend.

Comment: How does Lacie Network assistant find it : as a network device or as storage? This is important to know.

Comment: I am not sure but it gives me an ip address to connect so I think its detecting in as a network device. It says something like click here to access the dashboard. if I click it open the browser with the cloudbox ip but then it says page not found

Comment: I think that explains it - I added to my answer.

Comment: ok. I have changed cloudbox to DHCP and now it works. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to connect to it when it is connected to the router, give it a static IP.  Make sure the Static IP you give it is in your same network.  For instance, if your IP address is 192.168.0.5, a good static address for the cloud-box would be 192.169.0.252.  Then disconnect it and connect via Ethernet cable to your PC.  You should be able to access it via the IP (192.168.0.252) you statically set in the first step.

Comment: It already have a static ip. (192.168.1.82). Now my Lacie Network assistant can find it but I still cant access it. My PC ip address is 192.168.1.59 (DHCP).I have tried in other computer and its the same thing. I am having some problems with my PC right now. I will test it again it weekend.